# Does the weight of a pilot exponentially affect the necessary weight of human-powered aircraft?

Tags: structural-engineering, structural-analysis, structures, aerospace-engineering, aerodynamics

The [MIT Daedalus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_Daedalus), a human-powered craft, weighed about 31 kg. This was significantly lighter than its pilot during its record setting trip, though I can't confirm the pilot's exact weight. Still, this raises the question: If the pilot had been half the weight, would it have been possible to safely reduce the Daedalus weight by more than half (aka: exponentially instead of linearly)?

Since smaller birds seem to have an advantage over larger ones, I would assume it'd be easier to achieve flight with a smaller pilot.

Note that the pilot is not half weight due to being malnourished or lacking musculature. The half weight was meant as an easy example. If someone has an example for a 20% lighter pilot, that should be useful.

Comment: Have a free read of David McKay's [Sustainable Energy without the Hot Air](https://www.withouthotair.com/cC/page_269.shtml). I've linked to a chapter on flight, planes and birds which you might find interesting.

Comment: Square cube law.

Comment: @DKNguyen That does make me think it would be exponentially effective, yes. Wanted to confirm this, since others have strangely doubted this. I was hoping to learn a bit about the details and learn more about how size affects structure weight and strength.

Comment: @Nail All you really have to say to them is "square cube law". Then go tell them to lift a hundred times their own weight like an ant can. There's a reason pull-ups are easier for little guys than big guys, even if they are fit.

Comment: So are you making the assumption that a person with double the mass develops double the power? Or half & half in reverse?

Comment: @SolarMike Based off a 12yo biking champion, it's plausible the half weight guy would have more than half the power. But I'm not picky, I just want to see the concept demonstrated so I understand it better.

Comment: Is power effected by the square cube law? I don't think so, since it's governed by volume, instead of cross section. Of course a larger person still has heavier bones and lower muscle force per weight than a small one.

Comment: Check out Chris Boardman - 70kg and a champion…

Comment: @Drew Well, small aircraft have a *much* higher power-to-weight ratio than full-sized aircraft,

Comment: @DKNguyen You really mean power, not thrust?

Comment: @Drew Yes. The ability to vertical is the easiest to compare but so few full-sized airplanes can do that so you end up mostly trying to compare full-sized wing lift to model propeller thrust which isn't a very obvious. So it's easiest to compare by looking at the maneuverability of model helicopters where, at all sizes, they all must support their own weight purely with the rotor. The larger it is, the more like a pig it tends to fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple answer because there is an awful lot going on with planes such as *Daedalus*. That project needed to cover a specific course distance in ground effect over open water. And it needed an allowance for weather. If you go smaller, will you go faster, slower, or the same speed? Doesn't being half the size make the course seem twice and big? How will the aspect ratio of the wings change (spar weight is governed in large part by bending moment, which scales as the forth power). What are the Reynolds number effects on the lift and drag curves? Since you can't scale the weather, how does the perturbation and recovery energy factor in, and how do you scale the control surfaces and control power requirements? How much ground effect are you counting on and how does that work if the scale changes but the sea state remains the same? How does turbomachinery such as a propeller scale? How does the vehicle's stiffness matrix scale. How do the vehicle's stability derivatives scale?

Many of the above questions can be answered with Drela's *Flight Vehicle Aerodynamics* book. Then you have to figure out how to engineer and build the thing.

The way you approach this in practice is to rank order these effects as best you can, then run sequential optimizations where you add in one more constraint with each run. You may have to analyze and re-linearize the model each go. You can use  Lagranian optimization to handle the constraint system. It gets real messy real fast. You end up with a lot of heuristics to speed things up once you think you have the big questions answered.

Much of the design space of interest is fairly flat, and you need really accurate test data to get a good linearized model at each step. That's the real problem here - data on the real performance of built HPV wingsets is not all that robust. Particularly with regard to rigidity requirements.

So the short answer is that every single design variable is going to scale a little differently because they all influence each other. Many are inherently nonlinear, so you have make a guess and linearize around it and see what happens.

Here is the most common scaling list for sailboats, which have a lot of in common as far as problem set-up goes. The list comes from Barkla originally, I cribbed it from *Principals of yacht design* by Larsson and Eliasson.

> **Assumed**: L=Length
> Sail area: L^1.85
> Beam, depth, freeboard: L^0.70
> Keel, rudder - span, cord, thickness: L^0.70
>
> **Derived**
> section areas: L^1.4
> wetted hull area: L^1.70
> wetted keel, rudder: L^1.40
> hull volume:L^2.40
> Keel volume:L^2.10
> length/displacment ratio: L^0.20
> sail area/displacement ratio:L^0.25
> 2nd moment area lateral:L^3.10
> 2nd moment area longitudinal: L^3.70
>
> **Secondary**   There is a whole raft of more ratios that are typical for normal boat, but depend somewhat on the particular design being
> scaled.

In the above list, there was no attempt to optimize the scaling, they just used some basic knowledge from millions of boats and crunched the math for the derived figures. With miniDaedalus, you don't have millions of craft to use as a basis. And the scaling is only considered good for about 0.9 to 1.1 L.